# Map a class in hibernate that is in a referenced project

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using classes that are a in referenced project as the mapping for hibernate project - I am able to use the classes in Java code but cannot refer to the classes in the hibernate config file. I get `WARN: HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class`

so in the hibernate mapping config file I am using:

```
...

<mapping package="com.me.my.proj.oracle"/>
<mapping class="com.me.my.proj.oracle.WDI_HBD_PSNG_SMRY"/>
</session-factory> ###end of hibernate config file###
```

Is it possible to reference a class in a reference project using hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your referenced project (Java) is added as `JAR` file in your current project's classpath. I think you need to use `mappingJarLocation` with location as your `ReferenceProjectName.jar`.

```
    <property name="mappingJarLocations" value="file:**/ReferenceProjectName.jar"/>
```

Comment: is that done automatically - because it isnt added in my class path as a jar - not that I know of- will look into it ,ore